# Why is copying an array called "slice"?

Tags: javascript

I know what as slice of strawberry cake is and if you're talking about data I know that you can slice that up, and get shards or buckets.

I don't get it though, why in js land copying data is called "slice". What is the underlying reason behind this choice in naming?

Edit: the trouble for me was to realise that the word "slice" should be taken literaly (a realisation that would have led me to think this method is overloaded). English is not my native language and many times, wordings in API´s should not be taken literaly. More precisely, the word might have several meanings (definitions) that point in different directions (such as the keyword "map", which means several things).

Edit2: when folks talk about data, especially when it's big, they usually throw around words such as "map", "reduce", "aggregate" and "slice". Here's from pinterest´s blog, where they explain their big data storage solution and the meaning of the word "slice" seems to follow javascript´s thought of that same word:

"There are hundreds of Hadoop jobs slicing the data across multiple dimensions to produce reports that track our business metrics and generate derived aggregates that feed into our serving infrastructure."

...meaning, they have an original array of data that they slice to get new copies of that data. The original is not mutated.

My confusion and misconception of the terminology might be shared by others. Close this Q otherwise. Your call.

Comment: I don't think there is a precise answer to this question unless you can find the actual person who first decided to call this type of operation `.slice()`.  Logically, you can imagine slicing out a piece of an array or string to get a subset of it just like you slice out a piece of a cake to get a subset of it, but I have no idea what the original reason for the name was.

Comment: Is it really? I agree, that would be quite strange. Are you sure that slice doesn't do something more similar to its name and that copying data is just a subset of the functionality slice provides?

Comment: I'm hoping someone on SO who share the mindset of the creator of that API would chip in and tell me that there is a good reason for that naming.

Comment: you can copy an array `arr` by using `let copy = [...arr];` if you dont like the word slice

Comment: Normally, `slice` is used to get a range of elements from an existing array and save these elements in a new array. For example: `["a", "b", "c"].slice(0, 2)` returns `["a", "b"]`. Since we know it creates a new array, using `slice` to create a duplicate of the existing array is very convenient. Remember that arrays are objects, and they hold reference. Creating a new array is like creating a new object

Comment: @philip yoo that's the answer right there! Thx!

Comment: So, this whole issue for you is that you didn't know that `.slice(a, b)` takes two optional arguments?  Please visit [the `.slice()` reference on MDN next time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).  Making a copy of the whole array is just one possible use of `.slice()`.

Comment: If you search the internet for `js array slice` before asking such questions you would have quickly understood the rationale for such a name -- it is called like that because that is what it does. The first result is likely to be MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice.

Comment: @jfriend00 so what you are saying basicaly is "read the manual". Because this question of mine was really beneath you. Ok, got it.

Comment: Yes, we expect basic research on your own before asking questions here (as it makes the questions here much more valuable and useful and more worth it for the community to spend time answering them).  And any reference on `.slice()` would have shown you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will slice array from starting index to end index provided.

When copying array you use `myArray.slice()`. It means you start from 0th index and continue till the end. Make one big slice of array.

Comment: But "slice" indicates that the original item that was sliced is mutated, but the array that we `slice()` remains untouched.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `slice` was designed to get a slice out of the array. It is just a convenient way to tag along this function instead of creating another new function to copy the entire array.

See: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.slice

Answer (score 1):

> **Differences lies in english terminology.**
>
> *Copy is a subset of Slice.*
>
> Copy means make a new array having all the elements from starting
>   index to last index of the given array. So it just has one
>   purpose.
>
> Slice is to copy values from specified start index to specified last
>   index including first element and last element.